# How to get all the exception references from the try block?

Tags: c#, exception

I have a method that validates XML against XSD in which I try to pass multiple records. While handling exceptions I receive only first occurred exception as a message. how to get all the error references ?

```
    public static bool Validate(string sFileXML, string sFileXSD)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.Schemas.Add(null, sFileXSD);
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            document.Load(sFileXML);
            XmlReader objReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(document.InnerXml), settings);
            while (objReader.Read()) 
            {
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception eException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(eException.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you expect to have more than one exception ?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://forums.asp.net/t/1466198.aspx?Best+approach+in+reading+thru+the+whole+xml+and+get+all+exception+s+

Comment: @TimSchmelter if it is in the loop your answer covers it, I don't know why you deleted it. If it is in the xml Patrick Hofman already write something useful. The op probably should specify, because of that I'm asking.

Comment: @mybirthname: I don't believe reading is possible after an exception on the reader. You have to handle it before.

Comment: I tried that loop before. ValidationEventHandler got me what I wanted :) Thanks for participating :)

Comment: @mybirthname: i have undeleted it in case that it's helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [`ValidationEventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.validationeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) on the `XmlReaderSettings`. That will give you the opportunity to handle every event and exception on reading the XML.

The [`ValidationEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.validationeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has an `Exception` property which contains the XML validation exception.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you could  use the `Try-Catch` in the loop:

```
public static bool Validate(string sFileXML, string sFileXSD)
{
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.Schemas.Add(null, sFileXSD);
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.Load(sFileXML);
    XmlReader objReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(document.InnerXml), settings);
    bool success = true, canRead = true;
    while(canRead)
    {
        try
        {
            canRead = objReader.Read();
            // do something else?
        } catch (Exception eException)
        {
            success = false;
            Console.WriteLine(eException.Message);
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

Comment: Sure, in my opinion this isn't a solution to handle all XML validation errors, see my answer inside one XML document. (please let me know if I am wrong)

Comment: @PatrickHofman: i must admit that i'm not so familiar with `XmlReaderSettings`, but now i've found this which might be helpful: http://forums.asp.net/t/1466198.aspx?Best+approach+in+reading+thru+the+whole+xml+and+get+all+exception+s+

Comment: your try block is empty, how exceptions will be cached ?